# String 2012-11-09T00:00:00 to short Form of date in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I have a Date in StringFormat

> **2012-11-09T00:00:00**

I need to have it as `day=Fri Date-09`.

Many Methods i tried But the date is printing as Null.Can anyone help me out? I want to show it in a Custom Calender that i have Created.

Comment: what is your output with string format?? means you got 'T' between the Date??

Comment: s.The format i have Stated Above

Comment: now use my Method its working with T..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to get the desired values

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-11-09T00:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"GMT"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: dateStr];

NSLog(@"Date : %@", date);

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents =
[calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];

NSInteger weekday = [dateComponents weekday];
NSInteger monthdate = [dateComponents day];

NSLog(@"Weekday : %d Month date %d  ", weekday, monthdate);
```

We are getting the weekday as integer ranging from 1 to 7. You have to convert the weekday accordingly.

Comment: I think getting the day string from the week day number would be very easy and so I left it to you.

Comment: It Works Perfect.. Thank u a Lot,I was struggling With T

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        int weekday = [comps weekday];
        NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sun",@"mon",@"tue",@"wed",@"thu",@"fri",@"sat", nil];
        NSLog(@"day=%@ Date-%@",[arr objectAtIndex:weekday-1],[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

result for current date

```
day=mon Date-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method...

```
-(NSString *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) strdate {



    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: strdate];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
    return convertedString;
}
```

Comment: Please Look at the Format that i have Stated,I have tried this But its not converting

Comment: what is the T in string?? here main problem is that .. just remove the T from string and try its working great...

Comment: Unfortunately i should use the Format With T Only

Comment: it must to use T ?? if u put strdate = @"2012-11-0900:00:00"; in method and then see the output.. its working

Comment: S Its Working.. But With T is Not Working,I want to work with T

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18712/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-vanitha)